# Error while processing package libsimgearcore2017.3.1

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I recently installed FlightGear and it did not work out well (it crashed on my computer) so I decided to uninstall it. I opened Synaptic Package Manager and marked the FlightGear packages and its dependancies to be completely removed. I applied the changes and soon an error came up:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Since that, I have not been able to install or update any other packages. All other FlightGear packages got uninstalled except the above mentioned one. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Using Ubuntu Budgie 17.10 32bit. I found similar questions here but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then retry!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I will try now.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen It says this: `Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386 (1:2017.3.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~17.10.1) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/games/flightgear/Timezone': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386`

Comment: ok Run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Sorry but same errors are coming up. Output:`Errors were encountered while processing:
 libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Is no one going to help?

Comment: Please see my added answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, and I've solved it by creating missing directories:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/games/flightgear/Fonts
sudo apt install -f
```

After this, I don't seem to have apt problems any more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets try these steps:

1. Install the repository GPG key:

   ```
   wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` via `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://screenshots.getdeb.net/ xenial-getdeb games
   ```
3. Update the package index:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install libsimgearcore2017.1.3 deb package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libsimgearcore2017.1.3
   ```

Source:

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/getdeb-games-amd64/libsimgearcore2017.1.3_2017.1.3-1~getdeb1_amd64.deb.html

Comment: `Setting up libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386 (1:2017.3.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~17.10.1) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/games/flightgear/Timezone': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libsimgearcore2017.3.1:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: The error is coming again

Comment: I already have that package installed but whenever I install something or do an update this error appears

Comment: Were steps one and two done when you installed yours?

Comment: I installed it from the ppa for flightgear I think.

Comment: flightgear-related here too

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and only managed to solve it by commenting out the related lines in /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsimgearcore2017.3.1:amd64.prerm .

But be really careful (I wasn't quite sure of myself, but was aware of the risks ;-) )
HTH,